# Unidentified line in exported uv's

Tags: uv, error

Having trouble with exported uv's, the fbx's uv i exported from blender are good but when loading it in substance painter a phisical line shows in the middle of it.
[image: this is the model and uv in question, on blender they're alright]
[image: meanwhile this is the same model and uv in substance painter, the line in the middle is what's bothering me]

1.This is the model and uv in question, on blender they're alright

2.Meanwhile this is the same model and uv in substance painter, the line in the middle is what's bothering me

Comment: I don't have Substance Painter, I don't know how UV maps should look in it. But what I see in the screenshot looks like an image texture to me, I cannot really identify UV islands there. So why not just erase that part in the texture if it bothers you? I cannot identify any UV problem there as well as no sign of where this shows up on the model. So this does not even seem like a Blender issue to me which makes it off-topic on this site...